# Electron application installed in system does not open because "iohook" library used in the "main.ts" file

Tags: reactjs, linux, npm, electron, dev-to-production

I am making an application using ElectronJS and I am facing an issue.
FYI: I am using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) for my application. And I use a npm library called [iohook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook) to catch all the system inputs like key pressed etc..

So, I create ".deb" file for my linux using:

```
npm run package --linux
```

After this, I install the generated file using

```
sudo apt install ./fileName
```

Now, when I try to open this installed application by clicking on it it does not open. But when I comment all the code in "main.ts" file which is related to "iohook" and then create a build and install the application in system it opens up perfectly.
So, the main issue is the "iohook" library is not running in the production environment but runs perfectly in the development. What should I do to make it run in production as well?

```
Electron version: 8.5.2
iohook version:  ^0.9.3
```

I cannot use higher(or latest) version of Electron or else I get issues because of version incompatibility.

Edit: Here is the link to the project repo
https://gitlab.com/vgoyal23/electron-apps

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you get any errors when trying to run the installed application from the command line? That might help debugging the issue.

Comment: Hey, no I do not get any errors. The application installs successfully but when I click on the "icon" to open (or start) the application it does not open. It does not give any kind of errors anywhere.

Comment: `iohook` is unmaintained and hasn't had updates for Node or Electron releases in years (though Electron 8 should be fine). The issues on that repo recommend migrating to [uiohook-napi](https://github.com/SnosMe/uiohook-napi), or [building iohook from source](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/issues/373). I'm not even able to install Electron 8.5.2 to test, looks like the binaries aren't on GitHub anymore.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I tried to do the same using the suggested "uiohook-napi" but I am facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer in the issue below. I had to add iohook not just to /package.json but also in the /release/app/package.json.
Refer this issue https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/issues/414